# How MonetDB uses indexes?

Tags: indexing, monetdb

I know MonetDB is a self indexing databases but how does this actually work?. I would like to learn more about how this works internally. Does MonetDB create compound indexes as well or is it just per column? What indexing strategy is being used? I was going through this document: https://www.monetdb.org/book/export/html/26 but didn't find much about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash indices are created automatically when the corresponding relational primitives would benefit. They are retained and maintained.

For the secondary indices see:
Lefteris Sidirourgos, Martin L. Kersten: Column imprints: a secondary index structure. SIGMOD Conference 2013: 893-904
regards, Martin

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @mkersten's answer, since the Dec 2016 release, MonetDB supports "ordered indices" on columns, where all column values are stored in order so you can binary-search them (and obtain the record index in the table columns proper).

See: the [Indices](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/TableDefinitions/IndexDefinitions) page on the MonetDB website (which also describes IMPRINT indices).